# Keep alive stops working when adding div with :key

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-composition-api, vue-transitions

I am currently facing an issue where the `<keep-alive>` stops working after adding a `:key` to the parent `<div>`. This `<div>` and also the `:key` is needed, otherwise the `<transition>` won't work. Anyone got a solution for that?
Sorry i am not able to provide more code.

```
<template>
  <router-view v-slot="{ Component, route }">
    <transition :name="transitionName">
      <div :key="route.name">
        <keep-alive include="SpecialComponent">
          <component :is="Component" />
        </keep-alive>
      </div>
    </transition>
  </router-view>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like even putting you component in a `div` alone prevents transitions.

My test app components inside a `div` didn't do any transitions even if I don't use `<keep-alive>` and `:key`.

Why do you need to wrap it in a `div`?

Shouldn't it work so?

```
<transition :name="transitionName">
   <keep-alive include="SpecialComponent">
      <component :is="Component" :key="route.name" />
    </keep-alive>
</transition>
```

Comment: The div is needed, otherwise the transition won't work